# Em pl-sql posso atribuir o valor do SUM a uma variável?

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

No sistema tem uma variavel `vsoma` que deve receber o valor total da soma da coluna Valores.

Como posso atribuir o valor da soma `SELECT sum(valor) from PRODUTOS2`?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `SELECT sum(valor) INTO VARIABLE from PRODUTOS2`

Comment: No sistema? Creio que é só fazer a conexão ao BD onde vai estar a consulta, obtendo o retorno é só jogar dentro da variável.

Comment: @Everson joga como resposta :P

Comment: @rLinhares Feito! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize o cláusula [INTO](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems045.htm) :

Exemplo:

```
SELECT sum(COLUNA) INTO VARIAVEL from TABELA
```

O resultado da soma será atribuído na variável que você declarou.

Mais informações:

- http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_pl_sql_plsql_select_into_clause.htm
- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems045.htm
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163996/how-to-select-into-a-variable-in-pl-sql-when-the-result-might-be-null